# Why does Java think that HashMap's methods don't exist?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm doing a final project for my coding class (it's a "do whatever you want but include a `HashMap` and a `graph`" type of thing),

But my `HashMap` doesn't think that the "put" method and "get" method exist, or something like that. On every line that has a `get()` or `put()` call (I'll put a `*` after the semicolon on those lines) it says that it expects a `@` after the `.`, expects a `.` after the `,`, expects a `?` after the `;`.

I'm really confused because looking at our class examples I don't seem to be doing anything different than what we did in class.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

public class HashMapForFinal {

    public HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, Integer>>(); 
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomInt = rand.nextInt(7);
    map.put("correct", new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()); *
    map.get("correct").put(1, 1); *
    map.get("correct").put(2, 2); *
    map.get("correct").put(3, 3); *
    map.get("correct").put(4, 4); *
    map.get("correct").put(5, 5); *
    map.get("correct").put(6, 6); *

    map.put("incorrect1", new HashMap<Integer, Integer>());
    map.get("incorrect1").put(1, 6); *
    map.get("incorrect1").put(2, 5); *
    map.get("incorrect1").put(3, 4); *
    map.get("incorrect1").put(4, 3); *
    map.get("incorrect1").put(5, 2); *
    map.get("incorrect1").put(6, 1); *
    
    map.put("incorrect2", new HashMap<Integer, Integer>()); *
    map.get("incorrect2").put(1, randomInt); *
    map.get("incorrect2").put(2, randomInt); *
    map.get("incorrect2").put(3, randomInt); *
    map.get("incorrect2").put(4, randomInt); *
    map.get("incorrect2").put(5, randomInt); *
    map.get("incorrect2").put(6, randomInt); *
    
}
```

**EDIT**

Figured it out thanks to someone in the comments (Thank you), I didn't put it into a method.

Comment: It looks like this all needs to be put into a method, and you're just trying to put it in the middle of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Method calls are indeed correct, but they are in wrong place. You placed your code where fields and methods should be, but the code must be *inside* the method. Like this:

```
public class HashMapForFinal {
  public Map<String, Map<Integer, Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer, Integer>>();

  public void foo(){
    // rest of the code goes here
  }
}
```

Note also, for the declaration of the `map` field it's possible (and better) to use interface rather than implementation class.